# Seventh Cross Validated Journal Club

Tags: discussion, journal-club

Time for the seventh iteration!

To remind for those who are new to the idea:

- CVJC is a meeting on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold) where we discuss some paper and its theoretical/practical surroundings.
- It usually takes place on Friday about 18:00UTC.
- The paper must be OpenAccess or a (p)reprint suggested previously on a meta thread like this one and selected in voting.
- We will try to invite the author(s).

So, please suggest papers (each in one answer), and vote for your favourites!

EDIT: I see there are new suggestions coming, so maybe it is time to call the whole thing rebooted and set a new deadline to 23:59UTC 11.11.2012. For a fair voting, chl's suggestion gets -5 vote normalisation.

EDIT: Paper selected; as usual I'll try to invite the authors and then schedule the meeting.

EDIT: The 7th CVJC featuring [*Handling Missing Data by Maximum Likelihood*](http://www.statisticalhorizons.com/wp-content/uploads/MissingDataByML.pdf) by Paul D. Allison will take place on Friday 12.14.2012 at 16:00 UTC. You can register [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/18/ten-fold?tab=schedule).

Comment: Can we make the next paper chosen language agnostic. I can follow the code and function calls, but it's not as pleasant.

Comment: I registered, but how can I see the discussion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to propose the following article:

```
Paper 312-2012 
Handling Missing Data by Maximum Likelihood  
Paul D. Allison, Statistical Horizons, Haverford, PA, USA
```

http://www.statisticalhorizons.com/wp-content/uploads/MissingDataByML.pdf

Missing data seems to be an area in which all applied statisticians are, or should be, interested (I hope this is not a controversial statement!), and perhaps some theoreticians are interested also :-)

Answer (score 6):

I would like to propose the following article:

> Sheehan NA, Didelez V, Burton PR, Tobin MD (2008) [Mendelian
>   Randomisation and Causal Inference in Observational Epidemiology](http://www.plosmedicine.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pmed.0050177).
>   PLoS Med 5(8): e177. doi:10.1371/journal.pmed.0050177

This paper is of some interest in relation to some threads on this site, in particular those related to inferring causality from observational studies.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest: [A Better Lemon Squeezer: Maximum Likelihood Regression with Beta-Distributed Dependent Variables](http://psychology3.anu.edu.au/people/smithson/details/betareg/Smithson_Verkuilen06.pdf)

This will be especially useful for DVs that have ceiling or floor effects or that are bounded, it is also useful when the variance may differ as a result of the IVs. But the paper gets kind of technical.

Comment: I've seen this paper come up a few times, not just in Peter Flom's answers, and wanted to second this suggestion for the next journal club. In that vein, is one on the horizon?